# Why eval() function resulting undefined property?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to get the value of property within array of object which the array is a property of an object --> this.form.data.output[0].output_total. The array name, index, and the property name is passed as a parameter and assigned to a variable.

I have tried using `eval()`, and try to log to the console, but it resulted `Cannot read property data of undefined`

Here is how I call the function:
`(keyup)="form.onNumberChanges($event, 'output', 0, 'output_total')"`

Here is the code:

```
onNumberChanges: (event, params, index = null, properties = null) => {
  if (index !== null) {
    console.log(`this.form.data.${params}[${index}].${properties}`);
    /* I am checking if the string isn't proper, but its result as same as I expected --> this.data.output[0].output_total */

    console.log(eval(`this.form.data.${params}[${index}].${properties}`));
    /* resulting cannot read property data of undefined */
  }
```

I expect that I get the value within that (0/2/3/or any other number). Is there any clue?

Comment: How have you defined `form` ?

Comment: try `eval(\`this.form.data[${params}[${index}]][${properties}]\`)` instead

Comment: @NickParsons not working for me

Comment: @Wandrille form is an object which has data which hold the data retrieved from the API, and it has function. the property data of form also an object

Comment: I don't get it, for me `Cannot read property data of undefined` says that `this.form` is undefined.
Can you do a console log to be sur please.

Comment: @Wandrille i think i got the problem. Why the data is undefined is because the eval function is not the arrow function or even if it is the arrow function the scope doesn't know the this.form.data, so the this.form doesn't refers to form object. But i still looking for how to pass the `this.form.data` to eval function so the eval function know the value passed to eval is refers to this.form.data. Any clue mate?

Comment: No, no! eval accept `this` from your component. Just do `console.log(this.form)` and you will see `undefined`.
Maybe, you have not initialized correctly `this.form`

Comment: i initialized like this ` form = { data: null as ICSInoculationInformation }` ICSInoculationInformation is an interface. when i `console.log(this.form)` the `this.form` is logged properly

Answer (score 0):

Try changing function to below as it looks like context(this) related issue as form is undefined

```
onNumberChanges(event, params, index = null, properties = null) {
```

and also convert to

```
console.log(this.form.data[params][index][properties])
```

Answer (score 0):

In which browser are you testing ?.

Make sure IE not support ES6 some methods such as `this.form.data.${params}[${index}].${properties}`